# Follow path with rotation in animation nodes

Tags: bezier-curves, animation-nodes

I have a bezier curve that I made multiple objects follow in animation nodes via the `evaluate spline` node. My problem is, they are at the right location, but not rotating along the path. They are all facing up instead of rotated along the curve. Is there a way to use the `evaluate spline` node or a different one to have the objects rotate along the curve?

My node setup:

[image: My node setup]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use a node setup like this:

[image]

then you will get:

[image]

Comment: How could I do this with animation nodes 2.04? My evaluate spline node only outputs position and tangent, not a normal

Comment: Just Use tangent ;)

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly!

Comment: you are welcome